# Will tags be removed?

Tags: support, tags, expiration

I remember seeing that user created tags might get removed in a few months later on some condition, but I couldn't find the rule now, what's the policy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags that are no longer in use (they've been removed from any questions that had them) are removed from the system daily. Tags that are only used by 1 question for 6 months are [also removed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags), on the assumption that they're not very useful. Finally, moderators can merge tags together, which will replace all occurrences of one tag with another and remove the former